# SQL Server hosting options

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-hosting

I am trying to find out what my options are for SQL Server hosting. The reason I am asking is because it always seems to be a problem getting the right kind of hosting for SQL Server. I mostly need a few small databases(<3Mb) for testing or to temporary store some data for clients when I am working on their website.

I could just pay 60-80 euro for a database each time I guess but that seems really expensive for a database with limited data and almost no bandwidth usage.

It can be really frustrating sometimes and it feels like I am always giving up some development "freedom" when I want to work with SQL Server. On the other hand it works so well with Asp.net so maybe that's the price I have to pay for using SQL Server.

So I was wondering how other people deal with this?

Comment: Thanks for choosing my answer as "the answer" Pickels...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are truly a web company, I'd strongly suggest that you consider investing in a dedicated server. If this is just for fun/experimentation, of course, then this may well be too expensive.

When I started out, I leased a server with both IIS and SQL Server already installed (managed by MaximumASP, btw) and then added Databases and Sites to the server as needed.  I believe that you can even do this with "Virtual" dedicated servers to keep costs fairly low (e.g. < $100 / month).  Growth, of course, will push you to more sophisticated configurations like it did for me (e.g. dedicated SQL Servers, multiple server web farm, etc.).  But if you don't start out with a solid foundation, you'll never get the growth.

Comment: I just started as a 1 man bussines so I don't have a lot of clients yet. 100 dollar still is a lot of money for me at the moment. I did look at dedicated servers and cloud hostings though. Something like cloud sites from rackspace seem pretty good and I am hoping to switch to a solution like that in like a year.

Comment: Good luck Pickels.  I started out as a one-man show as well.  If you always make your best effort to deliver great software and always take the time to listen to customers, you'll do well in this field.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sqlazure/).

Comment: Can you give some more info about how you work with SQL Azure. Do you just pay 10 dollar each time you have an idea or a small project you want to share with others?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your apps will play well with Sql Express, get a small virtual box for client QA and profit.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this? Is a virtual box the same as a VPS? I only have experience with shared hostings.

Comment: Yes, this would be a virtual private host.